# Reload PM2 from New Directory

Tags: github-actions, pm2

I'm wondering if it is possible to reload a pm2 process from a different directory. The reason for this is that I am using self-hosted Github actions to pull and build the project. However, while the build is running, the build folder is replaced with a new build folder, causing some requests to return a 500 status. If I could build and reload the application in a different directory, that would be ideal. Is it possible?